# 502 Bad Gateway in nginx/1.4.6 (Ubuntu14 Digital Ocean)

Tags: nginx

I'm install PHP7.0, Nginx1.4.6 and configured as below but I got many errors.

**sudo nano /etc/php/7.0/fpm/pool.d/www.conf**

```
#listen = /run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock
#listen = /var/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock
listen = 127.0.0.1:9000
user = www-data
group = www-data
listen.owner = www-data
listen.group = www-data
listen.mode = 0660

server {
#       listen 80 default_server;
        listen 80;
        listen [::]:80 default_server ipv6only=on;

        location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri =404;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        #fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
        #fastcgi_index index.php;
        #fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }
```

Let see the Log:

```
2017/01/26 03:33:54 [error] 2976#0: *8 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 96.9.77.42, server: localhost, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://127.0.0.1:9000", host: "128.199.133.1$
2017/01/26 03:33:55 [error] 2976#0: *8 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 96.9.77.42, server: localhost, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://127.0.0.1:9000", host: "128.199.133.1$
2017/01/26 03:33:55 [error] 2976#0: *8 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 96.9.77.42, server: localhost, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://127.0.0.1:9000", host: "128.199.133.1$
```

Comment: service php7.0-fpm restart

Comment: Many times and reboot server too but the same

Comment: does not listen to port 9000 remove 9000 from 127.0.0.1;

Comment: in www.conf or sites-enable?

Comment: try in www.conf

Comment: or change the line from `/var/run/php5-fpm.sock` to 127.0.0.1:9000 in `/etc/nginx/sites-available/default`

Comment: I have disabled it in my question

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/134044/discussion-between-heng-sopheak-and-mwweb).

Answer (score 1):

you may need to set `listen.allowed_clients` to `127.0.0.1` & comment `group` & `user` sections

```
# only localhost can connect to PHP-FPM
listen = 127.0.0.1:9000
listen.allowed_clients = 127.0.0.1
# listen.owner = www-data
# listen.group = www-data
```

then restart php-fpm service, check if it is running on port `9000`

Comment: root@ubuntu-512mb-sgp1-01:~# netstat -ntlp | grep LISTEN
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1443/sshd
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:3306          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1505/mysqld
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:80              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      2760/nginx
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN      1443/sshd
tcp6       0      0 :::80                   :::*                    LISTEN      2760/nginx

Comment: there is no php-fpm process running ?

Comment: Yes I can not found it but when I sudo php7.0-fpm restart it send me php7.0-fpm start/running, process 2779

Comment: Do I need to reboot Server?

Comment: Run, sudo restart php7.0-fpm

Comment: root@ubuntu-512mb-sgp1-01:~# sudo service php7.0-fpm restart

php7.0-fpm start/running, process 3293

Comment: It's sent the messages process

Comment: @HengSopheak solved ?? if not check logs of php-fpm & also `sudo service php7.0-fpm status`